# Horizontal slide issue CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please check the below link :

```
 http://ifelsebox.com/7/k2.php
```

In the above link,the code is working fine. I have a slider in which there are total 5 photos. the slider starts from the 1st photo and then shows subsequent photos on click of the arrows.

However in the below link :

```
http://ifelsebox.com/7/k1.php
```

the code is exactly same except I have two similar sliders. Now the issues is - I am not sure why:
1. the slider is starting with the 5th image and
2. the 5th image is appearing twice.(Check by clicking the arrow).

I need to have all the multiple sliders to behave exactly like in the first case. i:e each slider should start with the 1st image and there should be no duplicate(like the 5th image appearing two times in the slider).

Below is my html for the 1st case:

```
<div class="photo-post">


                  <?php
                      $i=0;
                        $unique_seq="888094499";
                      $pic_counter=1;
                      foreach (glob("target/*".$unique_seq."*") as $filename) 
                      {
                         $i++;        
                      }
                      $total_pics=$i;
                      echo "<div class='post-photo-slider'>";
                      if($i>1)
                      {
                         echo "<a  href='#' id='".rand()."' class='control_next_photo'>></a>";
                         echo "<a  href='#' id='".rand()."' class='control_prev_photo'><</a>";
                      }
                      echo "<ul>";
                       foreach (glob("target/*".$unique_seq."*") as $filename) 
                      {
                         echo "<li>";
                         echo "<div class='photos-slide-container'>";
                         echo "<img src='".$filename."' width='500px' height='225px'>";
                         echo "<span class='count-span-photos'>".$pic_counter." of ".$total_pics."</span>";
                         echo "</div>";
                         echo "</li>";
                        $pic_counter++;   
                      }

                      if ($i==1)
                      {
                      echo "<li></li>";
                      }
                      echo "</ul>";  
                      echo "</div><!-- post-photo-slider END -->";
                      echo "<hr class='hr4'>";

                      ?>

            </div><!-- photo end -->
```

Here is the CSS :

```
 <style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  



 .post-photo-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  border-radius: 4px;
 }

 .post-photo-slider ul {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
 }

 .post-photo-slider ul li {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 500px;
   height: 230px;


 }

 a.control_prev_photo,a.control_next_photo {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
   display: block;
   padding: 1% 1%;
  width: auto;
   height: auto;
   background: #2a2a2a;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.5;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 a.control_prev_photo:hover, a.control_next_photo:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 }

 a.control_prev_photo {
   border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
 } 

 a.control_next_photo {
   right: 0;
   border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
 }







 .photo-post{}
 .h4-1{margin:0;padding-top:8px;padding-left:10px;padding-    right:10px;padding-bottom:3px;display:block;font-size:80%;font-family: Arial,    'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:justify;}
 .post-photo-slider{}
 .control_next_photo{}
 .control_prev_photo
 .photos-slide-container{text-align:center;padding:10px;position:relative}
 .count-span-photos{position:absolute;right:20px;bottom:15px;font-    size:250%;color:red}
 .hr4{margin:0;padding:0;border-color:#FAFAFA;}



 </style>
```

And here is the js :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {



var slideCount = $('.post-photo-slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('.post-photo-slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('.post-photo-slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('.post-photo-slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

 $('.post-photo-slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

     $('.post-photo-slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.post-photo-slider ul');

function moveLeft(element) {
  var ulEle = element.find('ul');
  ulEle.animate({
    left: + slideWidth
  }, 200, function () {
    ulEle.find('li:last-child').prependTo(ulEle);
    ulEle.css('left', '');
  });
};

    function moveRight_old(a) {
      alert('#'+a+' ul');
      $('#'+a+' ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        $('#post-photo-slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#post-photo-slider ul');
        $('#post-photo-slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

function moveRight(element) {
  var ulEle = element.find('ul');
  ulEle.animate({
    left: - slideWidth
  }, 200, function () {
   ulEle.find('li:first-child').appendTo(ulEle);
   ulEle.css('left', '');
  });
};






$('a.control_prev_photo').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  moveLeft($(e.target).closest('div.post-photo-slider'));
  });

$('a.control_next_photo').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
moveRight($(e.target).closest('div.post-photo-slider'));
  });


});
```

Comment: I have removed $('.post-photo-slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth }); andn it resolved the second issue. for first issue, it is now starting from 2nd image

Comment: kinda hard to tell what image it's starting at, cos you've no pause in it, the photos don't stay up for any interval! Fix that!